# Save a draft message using 'hello sms' app

Tags: sms, drafts

I have started using [hello sms](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hellotext.hello) as my everyday SMS app and it is great. One problem though is I cannot work out how to save a draft message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save new message as draft, it works the following way:

- Open Hello SMS and click on '+' button.
- Type in your contacts & your message in their respective fields.
- You can exit app by pressing either 'back' button or 'home' button. Both way it handles the draft.
- Now when you again open app, just click on '+' button and you will have your previously entered contacts and your message body in their respective fields.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to save multiple drafts, it works the following way:

- Open thread of the recipient to whom you wanna send text and type in your message.
- You can exit app and when you return again, just open respective recipient's thread and you will find your draft message.

You can have multiple drafts for multiple contacts in their respective message threads.

Comment: Ah right thanks. So theres no way to save multiple draft messages? When using the default Android messaging app I used tobuse drafts to save notes, lists etc.

Comment: Yes, you can save multiple drafts. Please view the updated answer.